# Did Morgan Freeman say "Oppression is being told you can't say certain words because you will offend someone else"?

Tags: quotes

[image: Quote]

A friend sent me [an image of Morgan Freeman](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a1/2a/ba/a12abadf52a951d9407118e8202e95fb.jpg) with the following phrase as subtitle, assuring that the man himself said it:

> "Oppression is not hearing a word that offends you. Oppression is being told you can't say certain words because you will offend someone else"

But when I googled it, I could only find posts related to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/msblairewhite/status/760993043273043969), so I'm assuming this woman said it, not Morgan Freeman. But when I said that to my friend, he insisted Mr. Freeman said it first.

So, does anyone know for a fact if Morgan Freeman said this phrase?

Comment: The picture is not, strictly speaking, a claim that Morgan Freeman said it. It's just some words over the top of a frequently used picture of him.

Comment: @DJClayworth The implication is clear to everyone who looks at it (except you, I guess): This is a thing that was said by Morgan Freeman, and quite possibly this image is from a recording of him saying it. That's what such an image composition always implies. It borrows on the credibility and respect of Morgan Freeman to lend emphasis and weight to the quote by attaching one to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through all of Morgan Freeman's quotes in the website BrainyQuote, he didn't say this, but this was said by Blaire White (random YouTuber).

source: [All of Morgan Freeman's Quotes](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/m/morgan_freeman.html)

Comment: Can you [edit] in the link to BrainyQuote?

Comment: BrainyQuote does not actually include everything Morgan Freeman has ever said, and I would argue one would have to search more than it alone to even make the less strict argument of "there is no evidence he has ever said this"

As for the post script. It is really nonsensical. Morgan Freeman's personality is "black"? and therefore anything said regarding blacks fits his personality? you should include a citation that proves this.

You seem to leave out the only importation citation to the entire question, the citation of someone else being the origin of this quote.

Comment: Where is the reference that shows that Blaire White said this?

Comment: @oddthinking In the question :)

Comment: Brainyquote is not a reliable source. It's full of misquotes and misattributions.  Try Wikiquote, which cites the origin of any quote they include, or else marks it as dubious.